# Symfony form values to array

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

How can I get form values in an array instead of doing

> array('field1'=>$this->getValue('field1'), 'field2'=>$this->getValue('field2')...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

`$result = $this->getValues();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$yourform->getValues()` OR forms can be used as arrays. Read more here [more with symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) under the "A Form is an Array" section.